# Why doesn't box-shadow scale/spread proprtionally?

Tags: html, css

When playing with box-shadow's spread parameter of an element with radius, I noticed that it doesn't spread proportionally:

```
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px / 90% 90% 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: 100px 30px 1px 41px black;               
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/agqqge8h/

If you change the value 41px to another value in the box-shadow attribute, you'd see that the shadow doesn't look like it's parent element anymore.

I guess it has something to do with the border-radius. Is there a way to spread a box-shadow of an element with border radius proportionally?

Comment: Looks like you're right about this one.  Spread doesn't keep the shape of the original form, it just spreads the border, probably because it's intended purpose was to mimic a photoshop drop shadow as opposed to how you're using it.  I would suggest either sticking to a border, or if you need the two shapes to be set up like in the js fiddle, using a pseudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the spread radius **is not a scale factor**.

As you increase the spread, it will look like closer to a circumference.

[image]

If you want to scale, you can use transforms, e.g.

```css
tranform: scale(2);
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px / 90% 90% 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: 100px 30px 1px 41px black;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
div + div {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: But I can't apply transform on a shadow, right? I would have to create a second element or a pseudo element, right?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Exactly, the transform will effect all contents inside that element, not only the shadow. If this is undesired, using a pseudo-element seems the right approach.

Comment: Is there a way to scale a copy of an element down without using an additional or pseudo element. Something similar to box-shadow, but only that it scales porportionally. Does something like this exists? @Oroi

Comment: @thadeuszlay I don't think you can do this without some (pseudo-)element. But yes, you can "copy" an element an reuse it as a background image, by using [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element), but it's only supported by Firefox. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/agqqge8h/4/)

Comment: filter: drop-shadow(); can do this proportionally. But it only works in Chrome.

Comment: @thadeuszlay That's strange, `drop-shadow()`'s <spread-radius> does not work for me neither on Chromium 53 nor Firefox 50.

Comment: make sure the parameters are separated by a space instead of a comma.